# How to make refresh function in VBA

Tags: vba

I am using Access Database to make a program.

Here is the problem:

[image]

After I enter the data in textbox, which is in a blue boxes, and click 'Add Data' button, data move to the ListBox, which is marked with orange box. But I should press 'F5' button(refresh) to see the data. I want to see the data immediately after I click 'Add Data' button. Is there any way to do that? 
Any comments would be greatly thankful(It would be nice if you can share your code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ListBox.Requery` to the button's click event right after new data has been added to the ListBox.

```
Private Sub YourButtonName_Click()
    'Add data
    Me.YourListBoxControlName.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

requerying the form is the simplest way probably, but with no idea of what the button does, how your data is structured, how the form is structured, i.e. is the listbox bound or unbound, so cant really say, if F5, is doing it, then just look for the VBA method for refreshing the form.